# Phonegap/Cordova ... delete temporary filesystem after taking a picture

Tags: ios, image, cordova

I've discovered that my Phonegap/Cordova app on iOS is saving all the pictures I take with the camera and uploading them to a server.

In iPhone settings under the "use" tap there is my app and the disk size it needs is increasing, even after quitting the app.

So how could I delete these temporary files, or the picture itself, after it was uploaded to my server? I use the pictureURI to locate it for uploading.

**EDIT:** thanks. I've implemented the code and now it looks like this:

In my fileupload function I've added this line:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(fileURI, onResolveSuccess, faillocal);
```

and the other functions look like:

```
function onResolveSuccess(fileEntry) {
  console.log(fileEntry.name);
  entry.remove(entrysuccess, failresolve);
}

function entrysuccess(entry) {
  console.log("Removal succeeded");
}

function failresolve(error) {
  alert('Error removing directory: ' + error.code);
}

function faillocal(evt) {
  console.log(evt.target.error.code);
}
```

But it doesn't work. File is uploaded, but no alert, no console writing, no deleting at all...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to take the picture URI and pass it to [window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_file_file.md.html#LocalFileSystem_resolve_local_file_system_uri_quick_example) and then in the success callback of this method you will get a [FileEntry](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileEntry) object which you can call the [remove](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_file_file.md.html#FileEntry_remove) method on.

Comment: thanks for the answer. can you have a look at my edit in the opening-question?!

Comment: oh maaaan. it seems not that it works. i've accidentally used the term "fileURI" instead of "imageURI". i've just tested it in xcode (simulator) but in a few minutes i will test it on a real device. hope it works as well. thanks!!

Comment: i mean that "it seems that it works now" .. not "it seems not that it works" :)

Comment: ok, now i've tested it on my real device. works perfect!! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure which version of PhoneGap / Cordova this cleanup method was introduced, but it looks to do what you need, with a lot less code: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_camera_camera.cleanup.md.html#camera.cleanup